# Visualization of filters in convolution neural networks

Tags: neural-network, visualization, convolution

I read this article "[ufldf](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Visualizing_a_Trained_Autoencoder)", it evolves visualization of hidden layers in autoencoder, but I'm confused how to visualize filters for a convolution neural networks.  In my opinion, for the first convolution layer, to visualize filters, it need this equation:

[image]

And for second convolution layer, it should project filters into original input space, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your question here: http://metaoptimize.com/qa/ (there are more machine learning experts)

Answer (score 1):

In convolutional neural networks visualization of convolution kernels is the same as filters visualization. The only need for divider in equation you're mentioning is normalization. So it's needed only for better visualization.

If you want to visualize second convolutional layer filter you can just do the same operation.
You might also want to visualize those filters projected onto input space. In this case you need to compute convolutions of all filters of second layer with all filters of first layer. This should be 'full' convolution. If you have intermediate pooling layer, you should unpool the filters correspondingly.

So, for example, consider the conv net with the following configuration: 
1) C-layer: 1 input of size 32x32, 6 kernels of size 5x5; 2) Subsampling layer with 2x2 ratio; 3) C-layer: 6 inputs of size 14x14 (because of convolution and pooling) and 16 kernels of size 7x7; 4)... some other higher layers

In order to visualize 3rd layer kernels from this network projected onto input space you need to take every 7x7 kernel, upsample it 2 times, then make 'full' convolution with first layer kernel, this will give you 16x6 filters of size 22x22